# Shellshock and PHP fastcgi

Tags: php, shellshock, bash

I understand that running apache/mod_php is safe, but I havn't heard about the case of running php in fastcgi mode (via nginx/php5-fpm), so, anyone can confirm this is also safe?

Comment: fastcgi seems safe, as long as you dont switch safe_mode on

Answer (score 6):

FastCGI communicates between the webserver and the CGI host using IPC rather than environment variables, so the main attack vector (the webserver setting environment variables for CGI) is gone.  However, it is still possible for you to be attacked if your PHP script itself sets environment variables based on user input before executing `bash`.

Comment: +1 seems ok to me. downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Is there any reference that points out fast CGI is safe ?